# Oracle query to display 'ORACLE' in column fashion

Tags: oracle, split

how to display word 'ORACLE' into column fashion?

output should be like this;

```
output
------
O
R
A
C
L
E
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: output should be O then in next line R and then  A and so on!

Comment: Do you need a single record or a record for each character? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: show your code otherwise people will asume you want us to do your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUBSTR` and `CONNECT BY`

```
SELECT substr('ORACLE', LEVEL, 1) AS l
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < = LENGTH('ORACLE');
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/924)

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

```
select 'O
R
A
C
L
E' as "output"
from dual;

select replace('O R A C L E',' ',chr(10)) as "output"
from   dual;

select column_value as "output"
from   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('O','R','A','C','L','E'));
```

Though perhaps what you are really after is this:

```
select regexp_replace('ORACLE','(.)', '\1'||chr(10))
from   dual;
```

or this:

```
with demo (text) as
     ( select 'ORACLE' from dual )
select substr(text,rownum,1)
from   demo
connect by rownum <= length(text);
```